# android.view.InflateException Binary XML file line #53

Tags: android, exception, view, android-inflate

In my app I have a listview, that is a feed of posts, when I'm navigation through the app, sometimes the app stops and the logcat displays the following message:

```
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290): Process: com.codal.whatsee, PID: 6290
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class <unknown>
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at com.codal.whatsee.adapter.FeedRowAdapter.getView(FeedRowAdapter.java:114)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1349)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1620)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
07-29 16:58:06.855: E/AndroidRuntime(6290):     at a
```

Sometimes it gives an out of memory error, it has influence in this?

Anybody could help me?
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Here is the adapter for my listview

```
public class FeedRowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FeedView> {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<FeedView> items;
    private FeedView objBean;
    private int row;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private AddRatingTask mRatingTask = null;
    private DeleteTask deleteTask = null;
    private float rate;
    private String id;
    private String token;
    private AuthManager session;
    private RatingBar rb;
    private float lastRate;
    private int itemDelete;

    private ReportTask reportTask = null;
    public int code;
    private TextView tvRb;
    protected int posRating;
    protected String myLastRating;

    public FeedRowAdapter(Activity act, int resource, List<FeedView> arrayList)
            throws Exception {
        super(act, resource, arrayList);
        this.activity = act;
        this.row = resource;
        this.items = arrayList;

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.color.grey)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.color.grey).cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true).build();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if ((items == null) || ((position + 1) > items.size()))
            return view;

        objBean = items.get(position);
        session = new AuthManager(activity.getApplicationContext());
        token = session.getUserDetails().getToken();

        id = objBean.getId();
        holder.tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameUserPost);
        holder.tvDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textPost);
        holder.tvLocation = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.locationUserPost);
        // holder.tvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.datePost);
        holder.imgUserView = (RoundedImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.imgUserPost);
        holder.imgPostView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPostItem);
        holder.tvRating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFollowing);
        holder.pbar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbarPost);
        holder.pbarImgPost = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbarImgPost);
        holder.ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        holder.btComentar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_comentar);
        holder.tvTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        holder.btReport = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bt_report);

        rate = Float.valueOf(objBean.getMyRating());

        holder.tvTitle.setText(objBean.getNome());
        holder.tvLocation.setText(objBean.getLocation());
        // holder.tvDate.setText(objBean.getData());
        holder.tvRating.setText(objBean.getRating());
        holder.ratingBar.setRating(rate);
        holder.ratingBar.setTag(position);

        DateTimeUtils obj = new DateTimeUtils();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-M-dd hh:mm:ss");

        try {
            Date date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(objBean.getData());

            Time now = new Time();
            now.setToNow();

            long diffInMillisec = now.toMillis(true) - date1.getTime();
            long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMillisec);
            long seconds = diffInSec % 60;
            diffInSec /= 60;
            long minutes = diffInSec % 60;
            diffInSec /= 60;
            long hours = diffInSec % 24;
            diffInSec /= 24;
            long days = diffInSec;

            System.out.printf("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds%n",
                    days, hours, minutes, seconds);

            if (days > 0)
                holder.tvTime.setText(days + "d");
            else if (hours > 0)
                holder.tvTime.setText(hours + "h");
            else if (minutes > 0)
                holder.tvTime.setText(minutes + "m");
            else if (seconds > 0)
                holder.tvTime.setText(seconds + "s");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.tvTitle.setTag(position);
        holder.tvTitle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // int posDaVez = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag().toString() + "");
                int posDaVez = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag().toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(activity, ProfileFragmentActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", items.get(posDaVez).getUser() + "");
                clearImageLoader();
                activity.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        holder.imgUserView.setTag(position);
        holder.imgUserView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int posDaVez = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag().toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(activity, ProfileFragmentActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", items.get(posDaVez).getUser() + "");
                clearImageLoader();
                activity.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        holder.btReport.setTag(position);
        holder.btReport.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int posDaVez = Integer.valueOf(v.getTag().toString());
                final String id = items.get(posDaVez).getId();
                final String idUser = items.get(posDaVez).getUser();

                final String[] options;

                final String[] optionsMyPost = {
                        activity.getResources().getString(R.string.txtDelete),
                        activity.getResources()
                                .getString(R.string.textCancelar) };

                final String[] optionsPost = {
                        activity.getResources().getString(R.string.txtReport),
                        activity.getResources()
                                .getString(R.string.textCancelar) };

                if (session.getUserDetails().getId().equals(idUser)) {
                    options = optionsMyPost;
                } else {
                    options = optionsPost;
                }

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                builder.setTitle(activity.getResources().getString(
                        R.string.txtOptions));
                builder.setItems(options,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                if (options[item].equals(activity
                                        .getResources().getString(
                                                R.string.txtReport))) {
                                    reportTask = new ReportTask();
                                    reportTask.execute(id);
                                } else if (options[item].equals(activity
                                        .getResources().getString(
                                                R.string.txtDelete))) {
                                    deleteTask = new DeleteTask();
                                    deleteTask.execute(
                                            String.valueOf(posDaVez), id);
                                } else if (options[item].equals(activity
                                        .getResources().getString(
                                                R.string.textCancelar))) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                builder.show();
            }
        });

        // Pattern to find if there's a hash tag in the message
        // i.e. any word starting with a # and containing letter or numbers or _
        Pattern tagMatcher = Pattern.compile("[#]+[\\S]+\\b");

        // Scheme for Linkify, when a word matched tagMatcher pattern,
        // that word is appended to this URL and used as content URI
        String newActivityURL = "content://com.codal.whatsee.fragmentactivity.searchfragmentactivity/";

        // Attach Linkify to TextView
        holder.tvDesc.setText(objBean.getText());
        Linkify.addLinks(holder.tvDesc, tagMatcher, newActivityURL);

        String imgUserUrl = getContext().getString(R.string.app_host)
                + objBean.getPhoto();
        String imgPostUrl = getContext().getString(R.string.app_host)
                + objBean.getImage();

        if (null != imgUserUrl && imgUserUrl.trim().length() > 0) {
            final ProgressBar pbar = holder.pbar;

            imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(activity));
            imageLoader.displayImage(imgUserUrl, holder.imgUserView, options,
                    new ImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                            pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                                FailReason failReason) {
                            pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                            pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri,
                                View view) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

        } else {
            holder.imgUserView.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
        }

        if (null != imgPostUrl && imgPostUrl.trim().length() > 0) {
            final ProgressBar pbar = holder.pbarImgPost;

            imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(activity));
            imageLoader.displayImage(imgPostUrl, holder.imgPostView, options,
                    new ImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                            pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                                FailReason failReason) {
                            pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                            pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri,
                                View view) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

        } else {
            holder.imgPostView.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
        }

        holder.ratingBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    // RatingBar barraDaVez = (RatingBar)v;
                    // int posVez =
                    // Integer.valueOf(barraDaVez.getTag().toString());

                    float touchPositionX = event.getX();
                    float width = holder.ratingBar.getWidth();
                    float starsf = (touchPositionX / width) * 5.0f;
                    int stars = (int) starsf + 1;

                    rate = Float.valueOf(items.get(position).getMyRating());
                    lastRate = Float.valueOf(items.get(position).getMyRating());

                    if (rate == stars) {
                        stars = 0;
                    }
                    holder.ratingBar.setRating(stars);
                    rate = holder.ratingBar.getRating();
                    id = items.get(position).getId();
                    myLastRating = items.get(position).getMyRating();
                    rb = holder.ratingBar;
                    tvRb = holder.tvRating;
                    items.get(position).setMyRating(rate + "");
                    posRating = position;

                    mRatingTask = new AddRatingTask();
                    mRatingTask.execute((Void) null);

                    v.setPressed(false);
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    v.setPressed(true);
                }

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    v.setPressed(false);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        holder.btComentar.setTag(position);
        holder.btComentar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(activity, CommentFragmentActivity.class);
                Log.d("Id Resgatado", items.get(position).getId());
                i.putExtra("id", items.get(position).getId());
                clearImageLoader();
                activity.startActivity(i);
                // replaceContentView("activity3", i);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        public TextView tvTitle, tvTime, tvDesc, tvDate, tvLocation, tvRating;
        private ImageView imgPostView;
        private RoundedImageView imgUserView;
        private ProgressBar pbar, pbarImgPost;
        private RatingBar ratingBar;
        private Button btComentar, btReport;

    }

    private void onDestroy() {
        clearImageLoader();
    }

    public void successRating() {
        Log.d("PosRating", posRating + "");

        // Subtrai o valor do voto atual do voto antigo
        float newRate = lastRate - Float.parseFloat(myLastRating);

        // Soma o voto dado com o voto antigo
        items.get(posRating).setRating(
                String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(items.get(posRating)
                        .getRating()) + Math.round(newRate)));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        // tvRb.setText(String.valueOf(Math.round(lastRate)));
    }

    public void clearImageLoader() {

        imageLoader.clearMemoryCache();
        imageLoader.clearDiscCache();

    }

}
```

And finally the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlItemFeed"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp" >

        <com.codal.whatsee.style.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgUserPost"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/perfil" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameUserPost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgUserPost"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tlClock"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgUserPost"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/purple"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textPost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgUserPost"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgUserPost"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPostItem"
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="340dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/textPost"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/montanhas" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            style="@style/starRatingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgPostItem"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:stepSize="1.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_comentar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tlRating"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bt_comentar"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_chat"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/comentar"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbarPost"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgUserPost"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgUserPost"
            android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locationUserPost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nameUserPost"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nameUserPost"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ic_place"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:text="Curitiba"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbarImgPost"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_place"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameUserPost"
            android:layout_below="@+id/nameUserPost"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_place" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tlRating"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ibx_lido"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:src="@drawable/star_full" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFollowing"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:text="210"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tlClock"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nameUserPost"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ImageView2"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_alarms" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTime"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="13h"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_report"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bt_comentar"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bt_comentar"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bt_comentar"
            android:ems="10"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="···"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="27sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please post some actual code. Thanks.

Comment: Show the layout XML file which is being inflated.

Comment: seems like you miss cased control or layouts name. E.g. might have written button instead of Button.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I can't figure out what is the problem.